# extract text from string in R

Tags: r, string, extract

I have a lot of strings that all looking similar, e.g.:

```
x1= "Aaaa_11111_AA_Whatiwant.txt"
x2= "Bbbb_11111_BBBB_Whatiwanttoo.txt"
x3= "Ccc_22222_CC_Whatiwa.txt"
```

I would like to extract the: `Whatiwant`, `Whatiwanttoo`, and the `Whatiwa` in R.

I started with `substring(x1,15,23)`, but I don't know how to generalize it. How can I always extract the part between the last `_` and the `.txt` ?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: regular expressions.

Comment: Add the `regex` tag and you'll get answers in the next 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp` capture groups:

```
gsub(".*_([^_]*)\\.txt","\\1",x1)
```

[image]

Comment: how do you plot this flowchart ?

Comment: using this (java-script style so can be different) [http://www.regexplained.co.uk/](http://www.regexplained.co.uk/), plenty of other sites that do the same

Comment: thanks, may I know why you only use .*_([^_]*)\.txt" to get the flowchart ? if I use entire ".*_([^_]*)\\.txt","\\1" , I get something different :-p

Comment: because the website takes javascript style regexp

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the stringr library with funtions like str_extract (and many other possibilities) only in case you don't get into regular expressions. It is extremely easy to use

```
x1= "Aaaa_11111_AA_Whatiwant.txt"
x2= "Bbbb_11111_BBBB_Whatiwanttoo.txt"
x3= "Ccc_22222_CC_Whatiwa.txt"
library(stringr)
patron <- "(What)[a-z]+"
str_extract(x1, patron)
## [1] "Whatiwant"
str_extract(x2, patron)
## [1] "Whatiwanttoo"
str_extract(x3, patron)
## [1] "Whatiwa"
```